# R code suddenly stopped working in tidy text

Tags: r, csv, text-mining, tidytext

I am trying to do word analysis on some data in R.  I imported one column of data that was text responses from a survey into R using read.csv.  I named one of the columns "text" . This code was working fine a few days ago and now it suddenly is giving me an error.  This is the code I am entering:

```
library(dplyr)

library(tidytext)

A1<-read.csv("/Users/Laura/Documents/A1.csv")

colnames(A1)= c("text")

A1<-A1%>%unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

The error I am getting now says this:

> Error in check_input(x) :    Input must be a character vector of any
>   length or a list of character   vectors, each of which has a length of
>   1.

My data didn't change, the code I'm using didn't change. :( I don't really understand why this is happening and am fairly new to R... Is there another package I need to load that maybe I had loaded before and didn't realize it?

Here is a link to my data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/amg12jp9qx98slz/A1.csv?dl=0

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Has the underlying data changed, possibly in such a way that R is doing an implicit type conversion and thereby throwing off tidytext?

Comment: How do I provide a reproducible example?  Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: See [how to create a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Ideally you should provide something we can copy/paste into R so we can get the exact same error

Comment: I added a dropbox link with my data.  Hopefully that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the data you provided on Dropbox and the following code seems to be running for me with no problems. Maybe try reading it in not as a CSV?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(readr)

A1 <- data_frame(text = read_lines("~/Downloads/A1.csv")) %>%
    mutate(line = row_number())

tidyA1 <- A1 %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, text)

tidyA1
#> # A tibble: 332 × 2
#>     line  word
#>    <int> <chr>
#> 1      1 empty
#> 2      1  your
#> 3      1   cup
#> 4      1  step
#> 5      1    on
#> 6      1   the
#> 7      1  line
#> 8      2  safe
#> 9      2 space
#> 10     3 empty
#> # ... with 322 more rows
```

Comment: So I figured out the problem is it is reading in the data as a factor instead of character..  So if I put stringsAsFactors=False when doing read.csv it is working now.  But I am still confused why I did not need that step before and now suddenly need to do it that way... Any ideas?

Comment: The code you used works for me now too.  Thanks.  I'm still not sure why I ran into this problem to begin with but at least I have some ways around it!

Comment: Ah, `stringsAsFactors`! It will [get you every time](http://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/)! I highly recommend reading data in using the readr library because it handles this more consistently and unexpected factor levels will not come back to unexpectedly bite you.